# "Упаковать" в Parcelabel тип данных ArrayList>

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Не получается "упаковать" в Parcelabel объект данных типа ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>. Задача - передать этот объект из одного Activity в другое. Вот код считывания и записи:

```
//Записываю
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "writeToParcel");
    parcel.writeInt(myArray.size());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array size = " + myArray.size());
      for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
          //parcel.writeInt(myArray.get(i).size());
          for (String s: myArray.get(i).keySet()) {
              parcel.writeString(s);
              //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "writeString(s) = " );
              parcel.writeString(myArray.get(i).get(s));
          }
  }
  }
//Считываю
public MyArrayList(Parcel parcel) {
      int count = parcel.readInt();
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array size = " + count);
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            myArray.get(i).put(parcel.readString(), parcel.readString());
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "myArray[" + i + "] = " + myArray.get(i));
      }
  }
```

Вот код в первом Activity:

```
protected void goToTweetList(){
    MyArrayList mal = new MyArrayList(tweetList);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListMessages.class);
    intent.putExtra(MyArrayList.class.getCanonicalName(), mal);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Вот код во втором Activity:

```
MyArrayList mal = (MyArrayList) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MyArrayList.class.getCanonicalName());
        tweetList = mal.myArray;
```

Примечания: 
 1. tweetList это объект типа ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>. 
 2. Тестировал свой код для типа данных String - и он работает. Склонен полагать, что где-то что-то я неправильно запаковываю/распаковываю свой объект.
 3. Видел в сети примеры отдельно для запаковки ArrayList и отдельно для HashMap. Синтезировать их, к сожалению, не получилось, поэтому и пишу сюда.

Спасибо!

Comment: Хм, а что выдаёт закомментированный лог, если его раскомментировать?

Comment: Ничего не выдает. При переходе ко второму Activity при попытке создать объект MyArrayList у меня происходит вылет приложения. Где-то неправильно запаковываю/распаковываю, а где - не понимаю.

Comment: Эээ, если лог ничего не выдаёт, значит, процедура вообще не вызывается. Ищите, почему.

Comment: Вызывается, уже проверял логами. Я данные распаковываю неправильно, все уже найдено.
Я же написал, что для данных типа String все работает и вызывается. Ошибка в самой функции, которую я не могу найти.

Comment: Не-не, может вы как раз пакуете неправильно. Включите все закомментированные логи и прогоните снова.

Comment: Включил, прогнал - пакую я все правильно. Не могу разобраться с распаковкой.

Comment: При переходе на вторую активность лог показывает NullPointerException, когда я пытаюсь получить parcel-объект.

Comment: О, значит, проблема не в упаковке в Parcel или его распаковке, а сохранении/получении его, ведь так? То есть до кода распаковки дела даже не доходит. Может, у вас не тот intent получается?

Answer (score 1):

вот, может уже и не надо конечно, вдруг кому пригодится.

```
import android.os.Parcel;

import android.os.Parcelable;

import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> implements Parcelable{
MyArrayList() {
}

@Override
public boolean add(HashMap<String, String> object) {
    return super.add(object);
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> get(int index) {
    return super.get(index);
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> remove(int index) {
    return super.remove(index);
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    super.clear();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    Log.d("parcel", "writeToParcel");
    parcel.writeInt(super.size());
    parcel.writeInt(super.get(0).keySet().size());
    Log.d("parcel", "Array size = " + super.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < super.size(); k++) {
        for (String s: super.get(k).keySet()) {
            parcel.writeString(s);
            Log.d("parcel", "writeString(s) = "+s);
            parcel.writeString(super.get(k).get(s));
            Log.d("parcel", "writeString(s) = "+super.get(k).get(s));
        }
        Log.d("parcel", super.get(k)+"");
    }
}
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    // распаковываем объект из Parcel
    public MyArrayList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Log.d("parcel", "createFromParcel");
        return new MyArrayList(in);
    }

    public MyArrayList[] newArray(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }
};

// конструктор, считывающий данные из Parcel
private MyArrayList(Parcel parcel) {
    int arrSize = parcel.readInt();
    int count = parcel.readInt();
    Log.d("parcel", "Array size = " + arrSize);
    Log.d("parcel", "HashMap size = " + count);
    //myArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int k = 0;k < arrSize;k++) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            map.put(parcel.readString(), parcel.readString());
            //Log.d("parcel", "readString(s) = "+parcel.readString() + " " + parcel.readString());
        }
        super.add(map);
        Log.d("parcel", "myArray[" + k + "] = " + super.get(k));
    }
}
```

}